# iOS app - data across devices

Tags: ios, database

I'm new to iOS app development, and am planning developing an app that will require devices to use data across multiple devices and stored centrally.

Typically I would use a database such as MySQL (this is where i store the data currently) but understand there isn't native support for this in iOS development (is that correct)

What is the best way for me to store that data centrally and make it accessible by multiple ios devices.

James

Comment: Will all the device need to share the same data, or is it per user? If all app need the same data then some kind of web service will be needed to sync the data. If just for one user you can use iCould. About how to store there are multiple options, CoreData, SQLite, custom object, etc..

Comment: For multiple device as @rckoenes suggest iCloud and Cloud kit (new feature of iOS 8) is useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different approaches to this and it will depending on the kind of data and what kinds of devices you want to target.  I would suggest using CoreData for your local data and using Parse.com for your backend.  Your app would push/pull data to Parse to sync the data.